# Axes3D Plot Wireframe from DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I'm working with Axes3D, and I want to create a 3d plot of two floats and a timestamp from a pandas series. The plot function looks like this:

```
ax.plot_wireframe(X = response['PCT_MONEYNESS'], Y = response['IVOL'], Z=response['EXPIRE_DT'])
```

When I tried this, I got an error

`"ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<M8[ns]')"`

I was okay with having the datetimes in terms of just days instead, so I went back to my dataframe and edited it with the following code

```
response['EXPIRE_DT'] = response['EXPIRE_DT'].apply(lambda x: (x.to_pydatetime()-datetime.datetime.today()).days).astype(float)
```

When I return just response['EXPIRE_DT'], I get a pandas series of datatype float, which is expected. However, the error persists. Is there another reason this error could be popping up, despite my not trying to plot anything with datatype `<M8[ns]`?

Edit: As requested, output from response['EXPIRE_DT'], both before and after editing.

Before--

```
ID
AAPL US 01/19/18 P85 Equity      2018-01-19
AAPL US 02/09/18 P170 Equity     2018-02-09
AAPL US 02/09/18 P167.5 Equity   2018-02-09
AAPL US 02/09/18 P165 Equity     2018-02-09
Name: EXPIRE_DT, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

After--

```
ID
AAPL US 01/19/18 P85 Equity        21.0
AAPL US 02/09/18 P170 Equity       42.0
AAPL US 02/09/18 P167.5 Equity     42.0
AAPL US 02/09/18 P165 Equity       42.0
Name: EXPIRE_DT, dtype: float64
```

Other two dataframes are series with

```
Name: PCT_MONEYNESS, dtype: float64
```

and

```
Name: IVOL, dtype: float64
```

respectively. So all three variables should be type float64

Comment: Could you post a few lines of the `response` DataFrame, preferably edited into your question? I'm not sure why you'd be getting the exact same error even after replacing the `EXPIRE_DT` column with a float representation of days from today.

Comment: Added all three relevant series data types.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
mdates.date2num(response['EXPIRE_DT'])
```